# How to create an algorithm to set a multi checked items in a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to create an algorithm that set a checked item in a RecyclerView. I have a RecyclerView made with boxes with a TextView and an ImageView, I use the TextView to show nameItems from a List and the ImageView to show a check once the user clicks on it.
What I want to do is that every time the user clicks on an item the check appears and every time he clicks on a checked Item the check disappears.

I create an algorithm which uses a boolean variable (isChecked) set to false, every time user clicks on an item the variable is set to true and vice versa.
In this case, a user has to click on the next item of the list two times to let show the check.
How can I do it?
Thank you so much in advance

Here is my Adapter's class:

```
public class RecyclerTypeListViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerTypeListViewAdapter.TypeViewHolder> {

    List<TipologiaEvento> eventType;
    private boolean isChecked = false;

    public RecyclerTypeListViewAdapter (List<TipologiaEvento> typeList){
        this.eventType = typeList;
    }

    public static class TypeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
        TextView typeName;
        ImageView check_icon;

        TypeViewHolder (View view){
            super(view);
            linearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.type_listed_linear_layout);
            typeName = view.findViewById(R.id.event_type_text_view);
            check_icon = view.findViewById(R.id.event_type_checked_icon);


        }
    }

    @Override
    public TypeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cell_type_listed, viewGroup, false);
        TypeViewHolder tvh = new TypeViewHolder(view);
        return tvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final TypeViewHolder typeViewHolder, int position) {
        typeViewHolder.typeName.setText(eventType.get(position).getDescrizione());

        typeViewHolder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isChecked == false) {
                    typeViewHolder.check_icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Aggiunto: " + typeViewHolder.typeName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    isChecked = true;
                } else {
                    typeViewHolder.check_icon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Rimosso: " + typeViewHolder.typeName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    isChecked = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just take one boolean value in the model class of your list. and in bindviewholder.
just put the condition like below

```
if(list.get(position).ischecked()) {
    action of checked
} else {
    action of unchecked
}
```

and on the click of the item you just have to change the flag of object and notify the adapter.